# in-mem-update.xqy not found in MarkLogic 8.0-6.4

Tags: admin, marklogic, marklogic-8

Has anyone faced the below error when running the application without admin user in MarkLogic 8.0-6.4

> Module /opt/MarkLogic/Modules/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy not found

The import is specified as follows in one of the application modules

```
import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";
```

We are facing with one of our users who is running the application without admin privilege. As soon as we assign admin privilege to that user, everything starts to work magically again for that same user.

Do we need to assign any specific privilege for `/MarkLogic` to resolve to the global MarkLogic modules (`/opt/MarkLogic/Modules/`) directory?

Or is there any specific setting we need to do for non-admin users?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need any special role or permission to access modules under /Modules/MarkLogic/.

Check if there are other imports on modules living in some modules database. It sounds like you have a custom library with inappropriate document permissions, and the error message is simply pointing to the wrong file. I've seen this before with the lazy evaluation of XQuery inside MarkLogic.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

We found the resolution to our problem. The error itself was misleading though. This issue occurred due to someone manually deploying library module with wrong set of permissions. Once we fixed the permissions, we were golden.